# Unitary matrix by conjugation

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, lie-groups, trace

Suppose that a matrix $M\in\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})\setminus\{\pm I\}$ has diagonal elements complex conjugates of each other and that their product is less than $1$. That is,
$$M=\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & \bar{a}\end{pmatrix},$$
with $|a|^2<1$.

Also, suppose that there exists a matrix $T\in\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ such that $T^{-1}MT\in\mathrm{SU}_2$.

Then, I think the following statement holds:

> $T$ must be diagonal, that is, $T=\mathrm{diag}(p, 1/p)$.

I would like to prove this statement and have tried the following:

Since there exists a matrix $T\in\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ such that $T^{-1}MT\in\mathrm{SU}_2$, then $\mathrm{tr}M\in (-2,2)$. The latter is easy to prove using the properties of the trace and those of unitary matrices. Therefore, we can deduce that $\mathrm{Re}(a)\in (-1,1)$. Also, since $|a|^2<1$ and the determinants are equal to $1$, we obtain that $bc<0$.

I have also written (using software) the matrix $T^{-1}MT$ in a very simplified way, using all the previous assumptions.

Still, none of this seems to lead to a conclusion regarding the elements of the matrix $T$.

Any idea or clue is very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $M$ is unitary. Then, for any unitary $T$, $T^{-1}MT$ is a unitary. So any $M,T\in\mathrm{SU}_2$ will do. For instance, take 
$$
M=T=\begin{bmatrix} 1/2& i\sqrt3/2 \\ i\sqrt3/2& 1/2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $T^{-1}MT=M\in \mathrm{SU}_2$, and $T$ is not diagonal. Or, to make a slightly more dramatic example, let $T$ as above and $$M=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}.$$ 
Then
$$
T^{-1}MT=\begin{bmatrix} 1/2& -i\sqrt3/2 \\ -i\sqrt3/2& 1/2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1/2& i\sqrt3/2 \\ i\sqrt3/2& 1/2\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}  i\sqrt3/2&-1/2 \\ 1/2&-i\sqrt3/2\end{bmatrix}\in\mathrm{SU}_2.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your counterexample. It has leaded me to 'relax' the statement, and now I'd like to prove just that such diagonal matrix can be chosen. There's a new question regarding that, in case you want to have a look: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3102359/285940